# Android project folders in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, project, structure

Can somebody explain what is different between folders "Android dependencies", "Android private library" and "libs" in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android dependencies**

Android Dependencies is a virtual folder where Eclipse shows what JAR files the project depends on.

**Android private library**

Contains `android-support-v4.jar` needed to support classes like `Fragments` in earlier APIs.

**libs**

Any of your personal jar file goes here.

Comment: That is Android private library can contains ONLY support classes like v4 or v7-appcompat? And there is different if I add jar like dependencies or add jar in libs folder? And can I add jars in android private library? Or it adds automatically?

Comment: @mjosh that is not entirely correct. The Android private library folder will contain the classes of any JAR you put in the `libs/` folder. The support libraries are there only if you want them to be there. Anything you put in the `libs/` folder is automatically added to your build path as a "private" library, which means it is invisible to outside projects, unless you explicitly export them in the build options.